# Is there danger of corruption in SQL Server 2000 databases when using SQL Server 2005 Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

In an interview for a SQL DBA position a while back, I mentioned I prefer the SQL 2005 Management Studio app vs. the old 2000 versions of Enterprise Manager / Query Analyzer. The DBA who was interviewing me said that they had experienced some sort of database corruption in their 2000 databases when making changes from the 2005 MS, so they always use Enterprise Manager now.

He was a bit vague, but I got the impression he was talking about some sort of corruption experienced when making server-wide or database-level setting changes, and not just routine SQL updates or something.

Anyone heard of anything like this? I didn't end up taking that position, so I can't follow up to get more info.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like he was just was using that as an excuse for lack of experience with SQL 2005 Management Studio. DBAs hate change.

Comment: I agree with Kevin (modded up.)  In three years on the SQL mailing lists I've never hears of SQL2000 being corrupted by SSMS2005.  I wonder if he actually had problems when upgrading a database from 2000 to 2005?  (Like the Maintenance Plan upgrade problem with SQL 2005 RTM?)

Comment: Well, he wasn't even (originally) the MS SQL DBA. He was the Oracle guy that got roped into supporting the MS SQL servers when the other DBA left.

Comment: I'd like to up-vote the DBA in this story. That's a great excuse for not learning something new.

Answer (score 4):

I have never encountered this, in almost three years of using SQL Management Studio 2005 to manage SQL 2000 databases. There are a few tasks I still bounce back into EntMan for, but I've never had a database encounter even the minutest bit of corruption. (And background: As a consultant, I'm managing about 45 different databases for both client and internal projects; most are heavily hit, and only about a dozen are SQL2005 databases.)

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with the interviewer because, according to Connect bug below, it is not supported to connect SSMS 2005 to SQL Server 2000.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/collaborate/connect-redirect

Thank you.

Comment: Your link just goes to the "MS Connect has been retired" redirect page, do you have any detail about the reported issue?